# Prove that Euler's equation can be written in a specific form

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

According to my notes, the following theorem holds:

If $y$ is a local extremum for the functional $J(y)= \int_a^b L(x,y,y') dx$ with $y \in C^2([a,b]), \ y(a)=y_0, \ y(b)=y_1$ then the extremum $y$ satisfies the ordinary differential equation of second order $L_y(x,y,y')- \frac{d}{dx}L_{y'}(x,y,y')=0$ (Euler's equation).

I want to prove that Euler's equation of the problem $J(y)=\int L(t,y,y') dt$ can be written in the form $L_t- \frac{d}{dt}(L-y' L_{y'})=0$.

Could you give me a hint how we could show this?

**EDIT**:

So is it as follows?

$$L_t-\frac{d}{dt}\left( L(t,y,y')-y' L_{y'}(t,y,y')\right) \\ =L_t(t,y,y')-\frac{d}{dt} L(t,y,y')+\frac{d}{dt}(y' L_{y'}(t,y,y')) \\ =L_t(t,y,y')-L_t(t,y,y')-L_y(t,y,y')y'(t)-L_{y'}(t,y,y')y''+y''L_{y'}(t,y,y')+y' \left( L_{y't}+L_{y'y}y'+L_{y'y'}y'' \right) \\ =y'(t) (-L_y(t,y,y')+L_{y't}(t,y,y')+y' L_{y'y}+y'' L_{y'y'}) \\ \\ =-y'(t) \left( L_{y}(t,y,y')\right)-\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}L_{y'}(t,y,y') \frac{dt}{dt}-\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}L_{y'}(t,y,y') \frac{dy}{dt}-\frac{\partial}{\partial{y'}}L_{y'} \frac{dy'}{dt}\\=-y'(t)(L_{y}(t,y,y')-\frac{d}{dt}L_{y'}(t,y,y')) \overset{\text{ Euler-Lagrange}}{=}0$$

Or have I done something wrong?

Also, have we shown in that way that the Euler equation of the problem $J(y)= \int L(t,y,y')dt$  can be written in the form $L_t-\frac{d}{dt} (L-y'L_{y'})=0$?
If so could you explain me why it is like that?
Because of the fact that we deduced that $L_t-\frac{d}{dt} (L-y'L_{y'})=0$ using the Euler-Lagrange equation?

Answer (score 1):

Notice (via chain rule):
$$ L_t - \frac{d}{dt} ( L - y' L_{ y' } ) = L_t - \left( L_t + L_y y' + L_{y'} y'' -y'' L_{ y'}- y' \frac{d}{dt}L_{y'} \right ) =y' \left (\frac{d}{dt} L_{y'} - L_{y} \right)$$ 
Edit: This shows ( assuming $y'$ is not identically $0$)
$$ L_t - \frac{d}{dt} ( L - y' L_{ y' } ) = 0 \iff \frac{d}{dt} L_{y'} - L_{y}  = 0 $$

Comment: I edited my post. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: You've just rewritten what I have? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Oh sorry, I retried it by myself and didn't compare it with yours. $$$$

Have we shown in that way that the Euler equation of the problem $J(y)= \int L(t,y,y')dt$  can be written in the form $L_t-\frac{d}{dt} (L-y'L_{y'})=0$?
If so could you explain me why it is like that?
Because of the fact that we deduced that $L_t-\frac{d}{dt} (L-y'L_{y'})=0$ using the Euler-Lagrange equation?

Comment: Yes, if you look at Euler Lagrange; we know that is zero. Equality reaches across showing the LHS is also zero.

Comment: So you mean that have we shown like that the equality because of the following?
$$$$
$L_t- \frac{d}{dt}(L-y'L_{y'})=0$ and $0=L_y-\frac{d}{dt}(L_{y'})=0$ and thus:

$$L_t- \frac{d}{dt}(L-y'L_{y'})=L_y-\frac{d}{dt}(L_{y'})=0$$

Or have I understood it wrong?

Comment: Think about it a little more, this is something that should be completely obvious. I've made an edit showing what I meant.

Comment: So we could start with $L_t-\frac{d}{dt}(L-y'L_{y'})=0$  and continue with equivalences till we get $L_y-\frac{d}{dt}(L{y'})=0$, or not?

Comment: Yes... that's exactly what the equalities mean, you're hesitation makes me doubt you understand what equivalence even means...

Comment: No, I understand what equivalences mean. I was just wondering if we can begin with the equality $L_t-\frac{d}{dt}(L-y' L_{y'})=0$ although we want to prove this but it is not a problem since we work with equivalences and we will get that the equality is satisfied iff the Euler-Lagrange equation is satisfied, right?